# Como puedo filtrar los datos de una base de datos con mysql?

Tags: javascript, java, aplicación-web, crud

Estoy tratando de filtrar los datos de un CRUD, con boostrap datatables, pero al momento de colocar una letra en el filtro no me filtra ningún registro.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.boostrap4.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#amable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Este es el script que use, lo saque de la pagina de datatables, hice todo lo que me decía pero no me filtra ningún registro.

```
<div class="container">
    <table id="amable" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">idPelicula</th>
                <th class="text-center">Titulo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Tipo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Categoria</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actor principal</th>
                <th class="text-center">Precio actual</th>
                <th class="text-center">Stock</th>
                <th class="text-center">Saldo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <%                    
            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
        <tbody >
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("idPelicula")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("titulo")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("tipo")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("categoria")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getString("actorPrincipal")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getInt("precioActual")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getInt("stock")%></td>
                <td class="text-center"><%=rs.getInt("saldo")%></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="editar.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("idPelicula")%>">Modificar</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="delete.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("idPelicula")%>">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="agregar.jsp" style="float: right;">Agregar pelicula</a>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

Así es como tengo el código de las tablas, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregando este atributo a un instanciador de datatable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#amable').DataTable({"searching": true,);
});
```

esta librería tiene muchos atributos que puedes usar para configurar tu datatable. también asegúrate de instanciar el datatable cuando TODOS los datos se ya estén cargados, de lo contrario esta datatable se construirá y pensara que no tiene datos. puedes probar, poniendo el script al final de la pagina, otra cosa, no olvides agregarle el footer

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">idPelicula</th>
                <th class="text-center">Titulo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Tipo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Categoria</th>
                <th class="text-center">Actor principal</th>
                <th class="text-center">Precio actual</th>
                <th class="text-center">Stock</th>
                <th class="text-center">Saldo</th>
                <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```